# How can I get every one decimal place number in a string input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string

```
let input = "1.0 2.5 3.0 4.5 5.0 -5.5 4.5 3.0 -2.0 -1.0 1.0 2.0 5.0";
```

In order to get a number array, I tried to do the following:

```
let output= input.split(" ").map(Number);
```

So now i got a number array. However, using the following code, I failed to format all numbers with one decimal place:

```
for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  output[i].toFixed(1);
}
```

```js
let input = "1.0 2.5 3.0 4.5 5.0 -5.5 4.5 3.0 -2.0 -1.0 1.0 2.0 5.0";
let output = input.split(" ").map(Number);
console.log(output); //got a number array

for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  output[i].toFixed(2);
}

console.log(output); //try to get all numbers with one decimal place,but failed
```

Can anyone know how to make this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need an assignment of the new value.

Comment: `const output = input.split(" ")` would be enough, assuming the input contains only numbers with one decimal place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an assignment or map the new values.

```js
let input = "1.0 2.5 3.0 4.5 5.0 -5.5 4.5 3.0 -2.0 -1.0 1.0 2.0 5.0";
let output= input.split(" ").map(Number).map(v => v.toFixed(1));

console.log(output);
```

As mentioned in comments by [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry), you could combine the last both mappings into one.

```js
let input = "1.0 2.5 3.0 4.5 5.0 -5.5 4.5 3.0 -2.0 -1.0 1.0 2.0 5.0";
let output= input.split(" ").map(v => Number(v).toFixed(1));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to iterate through the array twice? I'm thinking perhaps this: `input.split(" ").map(n => Number(n).toFixed(1))`